# Trying to webscrape a dynamic site using selinium

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm trying to web scrape using selenium in python. Here is the code I have so far attempting to print out the elements in a div.

```
from selinium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.golfnet.ie/clubs-and-travel-home/clubs-and-courses-search'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

xpath = //*[@id="listView"]
course_name_xpath = //*[@id="clubId-231"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]
phone_xpath = //*[@id="clubId-231"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]
email_xpath = //*[@id="clubId-231"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]

courses = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('//*[@id="listView"]')

for course in courses:
name = course.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="clubId-231"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]').text
phone = course.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="clubId-231"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]').text
email = course.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="clubId-231"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').text

print(name, title, email)
```

The site i am trying to scrape is https://www.golfnet.ie/clubs-and-travel-home/clubs-and-courses-search. I want to pull the information about course name, phone and email. I am getting 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with your indentation in your `for course in courses:` block. As Python is tab-sensitive, can you ensure that what you've pasted here is correctly indicative of the code you're *actually* working with?

Comment: I have uploaded an image as I'm not sure how to put code on here correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo in your import of `selenium` you currently have `from selinium import webdriver` when it should be `from selenium import webdriver`.

Code to loop through the results on page and get all of the desired items. EDIT: Added a for loop that will click on the next arrow to get the next series of items.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.golfnet.ie/clubs-and-travel-home/clubs-and-courses-search')
time.sleep(5) # Wait for javascript to load

i = 1 # Starts on page 1, loop ends once counter goes over 9 pages (current max)
while i < 9:
    result_set = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="listView"]')
    search_results = result_set.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

    for item in search_results:
        print(item.find_element_by_tag_name('h3').text)
        print(item.find_element_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)').text)
        print(item.find_element_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)').text)

    clickElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('icon-right-dir')
    clickElem.click()
    time.sleep(1) # let the page load
    i += 1
```

Prints out the following:

```
Abbeyleix Golf Club
0578731450
abbeyleixgolfclub_shirley@hotmail.com
Achill Golf Club
09843456
achillislandgolfclub@gmail.com
Adare Golf Club
061605260
golf@adaremanor.com
Adare Manor Golf Club
396204
info@adaremanorgolfclub.com
Antrim Golf Club
02894429001
antrimgolfclub1@btinternet.com
Ardee Golf Club
0416853227
ardeegolfclub@eircom.net
Ardfert Golf Club
0667134744
ardfertgc@eircom.net
Ardglass Golf Club
02844841219
info@ardglassgolfclub.com
Ardminnan Golf Club
02842771321
lesliejardine104@yahoo.co.uk
Arklow Golf Club
040232492
info@arklowgolflinks.com
```

Consider pulling from the data source itself to reduce the number of requests:

```
https://www.golfnet.ie/_vti_bin/GolfnetPublicService.svc/SP/ClubSearchPublicGridRead?&start=0&pageSize=9999
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  Please excuse my ignorence here but when I run just the code you have sent in the edited section to loop through, I should be seeing results when using print(email.text) on the last line, is this correct?  Really appreciate it!

Comment: If you are using geckodriver (Firefox) then running the code under my EDIT section should print out all the info you are looking for. You do not need to add anything to the code. To use chrome simply change webdriver.Firefox() to webdriver.Chrome().

Comment: I have tried running it with both chrome and firefox but neither returned any information, i get process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Did you fix your import? Is the module available for the interpreter you are calling when you run Python? Step 1: in the console, just run the first 5 lines of code. This should open a browser and open the site that's specified. If this is working correctly, then you have imported Selenium and it is available for your python interpreter. Step 2: How are you executing the script?

Comment: Did you download the correct drivers for selenium and put them on PATH for python to use? For Firefox you need to download geckodriver and put that in PATH and for chrome you need to download ChromeDriver.

Comment: Okay that must be it, I will go figure out how put them on a path in pycharm

Comment: I can give you the steps for Firefox:
1) Download geckodriver here for your operating system (linux/windows/etc): https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2) Put it in your python's PATH, the easiest way to do this in windows is to open CMD, type 'py --list-paths', this will list where your python.exe is for each version of python you have. Put the geckodriver.exe file in the same folder as your python.exe file

Comment: When running py --list-paths I get py is not a know command, I can find where python lives anyway, but should I be concerned that i got this back?

Comment: Depends on how python was installed on your system. When in doubt, grab the latest release from the official source: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ This should give you the `py` call.

Comment: I have already downloaded python before trying this, but to be sure i reinstalled.  When i type python in cmd in loads no problem, i have placed my chromedriver.exe file in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39.  I still don't get a window open when running the code.  I assured to change it from firefox to chrome

Comment: Could it be the interpreter maybe?  I uninstalled and reinstalled pycharm before beginning this project

Comment: Have you installed selenium in your environment in pycharm? The standard for python development is for each project to be an isolated environment. So you need to install the selenium package for each project environment you create.

Since you have installed python on your system environment, you could open python in CMD and run the code in there to get your results you need rather than pycharm since I think you are a little green in understanding how IDE's work.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't understand any of this before yesterday, I got selenium set up for the venv in pycharm in the end and it worked.  Thanks for all the help, I was a fair bit away!  Now I just need to try any understand how to make a button click  on a button to go to the next page of the website and take in the same values there.  One thing though, to find the elements we wanted to work with, you went to inspect in the browser, and copied the full xpath, is this correct?  I assume I can use this method to locate the button and simulate a click with a function inside selenium?

Comment: I'm thinking copy the xpath for the "kendo-pagination" ul class on https://www.golfnet.ie/clubs-and-travel-home/clubs-and-courses-search

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Feel free to mark this answer as correct and vote it up as well.

There are multiple approaches to what you want to do.
You can retool your code and pull directly form the data source itself as in @chitown88's answer.

Or you can put the current code in a loop and have selenium click on the next arrow every iteration of the loop.

Comment: To answer your question, about browser inspection. Yes, right click on the item on the web page, click on inspect element, in the Inspection console right click on Copy Xpath to get the xpath. Then paste that in the selenium browser.find_element_by_xpath('<paste here>') to get the element. I've also added a loop in the code to go through all of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of work and time when you can pull it all form the source in 1 request (and get all the info/data with it)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.golfnet.ie/_vti_bin/GolfnetPublicService.svc/SP/ClubSearchPublicGridRead'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'start': '0',
'pageSize': '9999',}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['Clubs'])
```

**Output: first 5 rows of 442**

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
         AlternativeEmail AreaCodeFrom26Counties AreaCodeFrom6Counties             BranchName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ClubAddress ClubCurrency                                                                                                         ClubFacebookUrl  ClubId          ClubKnownName ClubMainPhone     ClubName ClubNumber                      ClubTwitterUrl                                     ClubWebsiteUrl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Courses Description GUIBranchName  GpsPositionLat  GpsPositionLong  HasBuggies  HasCaddies  HasCaddyCarts  HasClubSets  HasDrivingRange  HasElectricCarts  HasPracticeGreen  HasProShop  HasShoes ILGUBranchName  MembershipAvailable  NumberOfBuggies  NumberOfCaddies  NumberOfCaddyCarts  NumberOfClubSets  NumberOfElectricCarts  NumberOfShoes                            OfficeEmail
0                                            057                   028  Leinster,Mid Leinster                          {'AddressLine1': 'Rathmoyle', 'AddressLine2': 'Abbeyleix', 'AddressLine3': 'Co. Laois', 'AddressLine4': '', 'Country': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Ireland', 'PreferredOrderIndex': 1}, 'County': {'Id': 13, 'Name': 'Laois'}, 'Id': 231, 'Postcode': ''}            €  http://https://www.facebook.com/116685651700096/photos/a.356637451038247.73588.116685651700096/507388262629831/?type=1     231    Abbeyleix Golf Club    0578731450    Abbeyleix        248               http://@Abbeyleixgolf                    http://www.abbeyleixgolfclub.ie                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            []        None      Leinster       52.921377        -7.339170        True       False           True         True            False             False              True       False     False   Mid Leinster                 True                2                0                  20                 5                      0              0  abbeyleixgolfclub_shirley@hotmail.com
1                                            098                 00353      Connacht,Connacht                     {'AddressLine1': 'Keel', 'AddressLine2': 'Achill  Sound', 'AddressLine3': 'Westport', 'AddressLine4': 'Co. Mayo', 'Country': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Ireland', 'PreferredOrderIndex': 1}, 'County': {'Id': 22, 'Name': 'Mayo'}, 'Id': 232, 'Postcode': ''}            €                                                                                                                    None     232       Achill Golf Club      09843456       Achill        394                                None                          http://www,achillgolf.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            []        None      Connacht       53.930122        -9.934649       False       False           True         True            False             False              True       False     False       Connacht                 True                0                0                  15                 5                      0              0         achillislandgolfclub@gmail.com
2  ghowie@adaremanor.com                     061                   028        Munster,Munster  {'AddressLine1': 'Adare Manor Hotel & Golf Resort', 'AddressLine2': 'Adare', 'AddressLine3': 'Co. Limerick', 'AddressLine4': '', 'Country': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Ireland', 'PreferredOrderIndex': 1}, 'County': {'Id': 18, 'Name': 'Limerick'}, 'Id': 233, 'Postcode': ''}            €                                                                           http://https://www.facebook.com/AdareGolfClub     233        Adare Golf Club     061605260        Adare        433  http://https://twitter.com/AdareGC  http://www.adaremanor.com/en/golf-hotels-ireland/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            []        None       Munster       52.572595        -8.773973       False       False          False        False            False             False             False       False     False        Munster                False               -1                0                   0                 0                      0              0                    golf@adaremanor.com
3                                            061                   028        Munster,Munster                    {'AddressLine1': 'Adare (Old Course)', 'AddressLine2': 'Co. Limerick', 'AddressLine3': '', 'AddressLine4': '', 'Country': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Ireland', 'PreferredOrderIndex': 1}, 'County': {'Id': 18, 'Name': 'Limerick'}, 'Id': 234, 'Postcode': ''}            €                                                                                                                    None     234  Adare Manor Golf Club        396204  Adare Manor        308                                None                                               None  [{'ApplicableDaysAndTimesOfWeek': None, 'ClubCurrency': '€', 'ClubId': 234, 'CourseDesigner': None, 'CourseId': 168, 'CourseLengths': [], 'CourseName': 'New Course', 'CourseType': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Heathland'}, 'DiscountGreenFeeAvailable': False, 'DiscountGreenFees': 0.0, 'NumberOfHoles': 18, 'OtherNumberOfHoles': None, 'UnitOfLength': {'Id': 0, 'Name': None}, 'WeekdayGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekdayWithMemberGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekendGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekendWithMemberGreenFees': 0.0}, {'ApplicableDaysAndTimesOfWeek': None, 'ClubCurrency': '€', 'ClubId': 234, 'CourseDesigner': None, 'CourseId': 169, 'CourseLengths': [], 'CourseName': 'New Course', 'CourseType': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Heathland'}, 'DiscountGreenFeeAvailable': False, 'DiscountGreenFees': 0.0, 'NumberOfHoles': 18, 'OtherNumberOfHoles': None, 'UnitOfLength': {'Id': 0, 'Name': None}, 'WeekdayGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekdayWithMemberGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekendGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekendWithMemberGreenFees': 0.0}, {'ApplicableDaysAndTimesOfWeek': None, 'ClubCurrency': '€', 'ClubId': 234, 'CourseDesigner': None, 'CourseId': 170, 'CourseLengths': [], 'CourseName': 'New Course', 'CourseType': {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Heathland'}, 'DiscountGreenFeeAvailable': False, 'DiscountGreenFees': 0.0, 'NumberOfHoles': 18, 'OtherNumberOfHoles': None, 'UnitOfLength': {'Id': 0, 'Name': None}, 'WeekdayGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekdayWithMemberGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekendGreenFees': 0.0, 'WeekendWithMemberGreenFees': 0.0}]        None       Munster       52.580046        -8.740260       False       False          False        False            False             False             False       False     False        Munster                False               -1                0                   0                 0                      0              0            info@adaremanorgolfclub.com
4                                            048                   028          Ulster,Ulster     {'AddressLine1': '45 Castle Road', 'AddressLine2': 'Antrim', 'AddressLine3': 'Co. Antrim', 'AddressLine4': 'BT41 4NA', 'Country': {'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Northern Ireland', 'PreferredOrderIndex': 2}, 'County': {'Id': 30, 'Name': 'Antrim'}, 'Id': 235, 'Postcode': ''}            £                                                                                                                    None     235       Antrim Golf Club   02894429001       Antrim        273                                None                      http://www.antrimgolfclub.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            []        None        Ulster       54.724300        -6.248562       False       False          False        False            False             False             False       False     False         Ulster                False               -1                0                  -1                 0                      0              0         antrimgolfclub1@btinternet.com
```

If you just want those 3 values:

```
print(df[['ClubKnownName','ClubMainPhone','OfficeEmail']])
             ClubKnownName ClubMainPhone                            OfficeEmail
0      Abbeyleix Golf Club    0578731450  abbeyleixgolfclub_shirley@hotmail.com
1         Achill Golf Club      09843456         achillislandgolfclub@gmail.com
2          Adare Golf Club     061605260                    golf@adaremanor.com
3    Adare Manor Golf Club        396204            info@adaremanorgolfclub.com
4         Antrim Golf Club   02894429001         antrimgolfclub1@btinternet.com
..                     ...           ...                                    ...
437        Leinster Branch                                                     
438        Connacht Branch                                                     
439           North Branch                                       denise@ilgu.ie
440           South Branch                                       denise@ilgu.ie
441        Midlands Branch                            midlanddistrict@gmail.com

[442 rows x 3 columns]
```